# Is it safe to trust a client with an update filter/replacement object in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How safe is it to let a client provide filter and/or replacement object, if I force userId:

```
filter = params['filter'];
update = params['update'];

filter['userId'] = userId;
update['userId'] = userId;

userSettingsCollection.update(filter, update);
```

What security issues might this approach have? Can client do any type of NoSQL injection here and update a variables for another user? What other problems might this approach lead to?